# Laravel - What's the difference between timestamp() and timestampTz()?

Tags: laravel

What's the difference between timestamps() and timestampsTz() methods in the Laravel's Schema Builder? I tried searching google but couldn't find any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basicly timestampsTz() stands for `Timestamp with Timezone` while timestamps() is like `Timestamp without timezone`

`TimestampsTz()` is a representation for a specific point in time. The adjustment to this time is made by the timezone that is related to your system.

The normal `timestamps()` is more a representation like normal clock.

Have a look at this example:

If you are using the `timestamps()` function you will also store the timezone that was chosen by your environment. If you are using the `timestampsTz()` you will not safe the timezone.

I guess it would be good practice to use `timestamp without timezone` when all your data is for sure in the same zone, or you got another layer over there which handles the time conversion.

**Update:**

In the Database the normal `timestamps()` will look like

```
2004-10-19 10:23:54
```

while the `timestampsTz()` looks like

```
2004-10-19 10:23:54+02
```

**Update 2:**

These functions are in Laravel available for every type of Database. But this only differs for PostgreSQL. Have a look at the docs: [PostgreSQL Timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html). In the other databases the timezone information is included in the timestamp automatically.

In all other databases this will have the same output.

Comment: both methods are creating table columns with timestamp data type. which stores UTC datetime. So where is the difference ?

Comment: Normal timestamp will look like '2004-10-19 10:23:54+02' while timestampTz() looks like 2004-10-19 10:23:54+02. what kind of database did you use?

Comment: I'm using my sql.

Comment: upvoted! how do I know if an APi is returning me local time or unix time, for example https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=ETHBTC&interval=1m&limit=3 what is this timestamp here? with tz , without tz, it works perfectly if I use timestamptz as the data type

Comment: @PirateApp guess you can just run it through strftime() mby ? not sure about that

Comment: The "+02" is not a timezone, it's an offset. It doesn't take into account DST or a million other "strange" behaviors of timezones.

Comment: ...and as many have mentioned, there's no difference in the resulting table structure, in MySQL at least. Apparently, MySQL timestamps/datetimes "support timezones" by "default" but to what extent and for what functionality, I'm not totally sure. Regardless, by all accounts Laravel documentation should say something to the effect of, "this doesn't matter" in anything but PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

`timestampsTz()` = Adds nullable created_at and  updated_at TIMESTAMP (with timezone) equivalent columns.

`timestamps()` = Adds nullable created_at and  updated_at TIMESTAMP equivalent columns.

The difference is that `timestampsTz()` adds a timezone.

Comment: both methods create table columns with the datatype datetime, which stores the date in UTC. So where exactly is the difference ?